# Printing values within a structure from a file using a function (in c)

Tags: c, function, file, structure

```
#include <stdio.h>
void output(score_t s);
#define STDNT 20
struct score {
char name[STDNT];
int s1;
int s2;
int s3;
};
typedef struct score score_t;

int main(void)
{
score_t new;
FILE *afile;
afile = fopen("students.txt", "r");

printf("N     NAME     S1 S2 S3\n");
printf("== =========== == == ==\n");

output(afile, new);

printf("-- ----------- -- -- --\n");
fclose(afile);

return (0);
}

void output(FILE *ifile, score_t s) {
int i;
i=0;
while(fscanf(ifile, "%s %d %d %d", s.name, &s.s1, &s.s2, &s.s3) != EOF) {
    i++;
    printf("%0d%10s%2d %2d %2d\n", i, s.name, s.s1, s.s2, s.s3);
    }
}
```

I am attempting to read a name and three scores from a file and print it into a chart using a function and a structure.  When I run this code I get this error message:
error: unknown type name ‘score_t’
Does anyone see what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Put `void output(FILE *ifile, score_t s);` below `typedef` line and remove `void output(score_t s);`

Comment: WOW thank you can't believe i didn't see that

Answer (score 0):

You are *using* the type before *defining* it. C programs are read strictly from top to bottom.

To fix this, move the method declaration below the type definition.